# Maven Overlay: Base project always starts tomcat on install

Tags: maven

I have 3 projects: parent, base and demo.

Parent is for global plugins and dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <Xlint />
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-run</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-shutdown</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Base is the basic Spring config (Servlet, Controller, ...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>base</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    </build>

</project>
```

And demo is for Spring JSP Stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>base</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>tomcat:run</defaultGoal>
    </build>

</project>
```

Installing parent works like a charm (Can find it in the local m2 repository), but installing the base project always runs tomcat?! I just want to build the war and install it in the local m2 repository. What's wrong here?

ps: I don't like to always mention dependencies and plugins, so it would be great to leave them in the parent project as I need them in every child (e.g. demo) project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `defaultGoal` is `install` and you bind `tomcat-run` on the `pre-integration-test`. So as soon as you launch `maven install`, it will execute `tomcat-run` while executing the `pre-integration-test` phase.

Checkout the maven lifecycle : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html to understand.

So you should update your `tomcat7-maven-plugin` and remove the executions. If you still want to keep those, then you should think in using some [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) (a specific profile for building foe example)